# Get RITM number attached to Change request in Service Now

Tags: servicenow, uipath

I am trying to get the Request number (RITM) that is attached in the Change Request (CR) in service now. I am able to get the Request number but not able to get for which Change Request the corresponding Request number is attached. I have used the table "sc_req_items" to get the Request number and "Change_request" table to get the Change request number.

Service now screenshot

[image]

I need the ritm number corresponding to the Change Request (CR) in the screenshot. how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Out Of The Box/Baseline Related list available on the Change Request table. The query that this Related List is using is the Parent field:
`parent=<sys_id/GUID for the change record>^`.

If Parent (reference field) is not the link between your objects then you need to map what the link is, is it another field or an m2m table.